# Change DateTime format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i return a date only format (DD/MM/YYYY) from a DateTime format column? example below

```
Modified Date
2007-09-01 02:00:00.000
2005-09-01 05:00:00.000
```

Output:

```
Date
09-01-2007
09-01-2005
```

Comment: You are asking for `return a date only format (DD/MM/YYYY)` but on your output that's not the format you show as it is `MM-DD-YYYY` with `-` instead of `/`. Which one it is?

Comment: [Convert SQL Server Date Time](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) will help you. @ThomasStringer has kindly pointed you in right direction.

Comment: BTW, if you don't care about the format and only want a date with the time part stripped, you can use something like `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as Date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some test sql for all the styles. Make nvarchar(max) shorter to trim (e.g. nvarchar(10)) .

```
    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETDATE()
    select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 0) as output, 0 as style 
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 1), 1
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 2), 2
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 3), 3
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 4), 4
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 5), 5
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 6), 6
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 7), 7
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 8), 8
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 9), 9
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 10), 10
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 11), 11
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 12), 12
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 13), 13
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 14), 14
    --15 to 19 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 20), 20
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 21), 21
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 22), 22
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 23), 23
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 24), 24
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 25), 25
    --26 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 100), 100
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 101), 101
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 102), 102
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 103), 103
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 104), 104
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 105), 105
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 106), 106
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 107), 107
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 108), 108
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 109), 109
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 110), 110
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 111), 111
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 112), 112
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 113), 113
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 114), 114
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 120), 120
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 121), 121
    --122 to 125 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 126), 126
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 127), 127
    --128, 129 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 130), 130
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 131), 131
    --132 not valid
    order BY style
```

Here's the result

```
output                   style
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          0
04/28/14                     1
14.04.28                     2
28/04/14                     3
28.04.14                     4
28-04-14                     5
28 Apr 14                    6
Apr 28, 14                   7
09:31:28                     8
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   9
04-28-14                     10
14/04/28                     11
140428                       12
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     13
09:31:28:580                 14
2014-04-28 09:31:28          20
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      21
04/28/14  9:31:28 AM         22
2014-04-28                   23
09:31:28                     24
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      25
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          100
04/28/2014                   101
2014.04.28                   102
28/04/2014                   103
28.04.2014                   104
28-04-2014                   105
28 Apr 2014                  106
Apr 28, 2014                 107
09:31:28                     108
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   109
04-28-2014                   110
2014/04/28                   111
20140428                     112
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     113
09:31:28:580                 114
2014-04-28 09:31:28          120
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      121
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      126
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      127
28 جمادى الثانية 1435  9:31:28:580AM    130
28/06/1435  9:31:28:580AM    131
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a particular string formatting of a `datetime` data type value then you need to work with the [`convert()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with a particular style.  In this case, you are looking for the style with a value of 110 (resulting in the format of **mm-dd-yyyy**):

```
select convert(char(10), getdate(), 110);
```

(*Note: I use `getdate()` just to generate a `datetime` value, in which case you would just reference your `datetime` column*) My output is this:

```
06-08-2014
```

Comment: Using your solution result is `2005-09-01` and `2007-09-01` but the OP is looking for `09-01-2007`. I guess OP is bit confused on formats.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '2005-09-01 05:00:00.000', 120), 110)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '2007-09-01 02:00:00.000', 120), 110)
```

Result:

```
06-08-2014
09-01-2005
09-01-2007
```

According to comments the inner `CONVERT` is not needed. But then, following OP question and provided sample data as `Modified date` the results don't match the Output suggested by him. Only if the OP is mistaken and all the time he is asking for datetime, as on the first sentence of his question.

[image]

Check this link for lot of samples on [Using Date and Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#ISO8601Format)

Comment: Why do an inner convert of a `datetime` to a `date` before the outer conversion?  No need for that.

Comment: Indeed for the `GETDATE()` case there is no need of the inner CONVERT, edited.

Comment: @Yaroslav you don't need to convert any datetime to a date before converting to the varchar. Lines 2 and 3 contain unnecessary processing.

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: When you have a string literal as an argument to `convert` SQL Server has no way to know that you meant for it to be a datetime. That is why you need to convert to `date` (or `datetime`) first before you take back as a string in the expected format. The style 110 is ignored when you convert from a string to another string. The only thing that happens is that the string is truncated to 10 characters. Try this `select convert(char(10), 'Truncated to ten',  110)`. It is not completely clear what data type OP is using but I interpret "DateTime format column" as the data type `DateTime`.